# Consume WADL in PHP

Tags: php, wadl

I have to consume a WADL and I am coding in PHP. I never heard about WADL.

I tried using [Nusoap](http://nusoap.sourceforge.net/), it works with WSDL but it didn't work with WADL.

Is there any library to consume a WADL REST API?

Comment: Try guzzle    http://guzzle.readthedocs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library that is simple and worked properly.

[Httpful](http://phphttpclient.com/)

It is ideal for PHP REST client, since I don't have to worry with  with curl set_opt pages